# Low Profile PCB Connector Identification

Tags: pcb, connector, breakout

There's some connectors on a PCB I would like to make a breakout for, but I'm having trouble identifying the connector type. Could somebody help me identify what type of connector this is, and potentially provide a part number(s) for the end that will mate with the PCB?

Sorry about the poor image quality.

[image]

Comment: looks like a common type of connector, but different vendors all have their own flavour. Don't think it will be possible to get an exact part without precise measurements

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know if the connector has a general name, or are there a few common vendors I could search for - in lack of a specific part number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like FFC/FPC connectors.

- These types of connectors are commonly used with camera sensors, LCDs, screen digitizers etc.
- The connectors mostly come in SMD configuration and use flex cables for the connection with other peripherals. However two connectors can also be directly connected and act as a male/female pair connecting two PCBs together.
- You can try doing a search for them at DigiKey, Mouser, LCSC, aliexpress etc. use the search term *FPC connector*.

[image]

[Source](https://www.dhgate.com/product/10sets-full-set-fpc-connector-8in1-on-motherboard/269845169.html) for the picture.